# Is there a way to use xpath 2.0 on Sonarqube?

Tags: sonarqube, xpath-2.0

I need to validate a rule over a xml and I need the regex feature, only found on XPath 2.0. I downloaded the last Sonarqube 6.1, but the XPath continue being the version 1.0. Is there a way to use version 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

From a quick look at the source code (org/sonar/api/utils/XpathParser.java) it looks to me as if the application is using the JAXP service API to instantiate an XPath parser. See what happens if you

(a) put Saxon on the classpath, and
(b) set the value of the system property "javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory" to the value "net.sf.saxon.xpath.XPathFactoryImpl"

Note that step (a) on its own isn't enough, because Saxon no longer nominates itself as an XPath parser using the META-INF mechanism - this was causing too many problems with applications that were written to assume use of Xalan.

This may or may not succeed in picking up Saxon, and if it does pick up Saxon, then it may or may not succeed in running it. There could be other problems - for example, I note that the XpathParser class in sonarqube creates a DOM with namespaceAware set to false, which isn't a good start.

Comment: we decide to buid a plugin, avoiding this annoying configuration